# Mac OS 10.12.1 - ImageMagick cannot read /private/var/tmp/*

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick

My system details

- Mac OS 10.12.1
- homebrew/php/php56-imagick: stable 3.4.3 (bottled)

ImageMagick is having difficulties reading from /private/var/tmp

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'Failed to read the file' in
>   /Users/myuser/Documents/mysite/upload.php:118 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /Users/myuser/Documents/mysite/upload.php(118):
>   Imagick->readimage('/private/var/tmp/phpsmBzDU') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Users/myuser/Documents/mysite/upload.php on line 118

Line 118 is essentially

```
$i->readImage($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
// $_FILES('image']['tmp_name'] is /private/var/tmp/phpsmBzDU
```

I see other session files created in /private/var/tmp too. Such as:

- sess_5pkmef95cq5ma9avc7ohrdbd33
- sess_pp35dfaopplge1jfjds8c54lr3
- sess_ctkpbica5dp2uunf2hrgqv4v12
- etc...

I have already tried the solution listed over here
[Set PHP ImageMagick tmp directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868089/set-php-imagemagick-tmp-directory)

Comment: Try `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`

Comment: Have you tried moving the file somewhere else using ```move_uploaded_file``` and reading the image then?

Comment: @emcconville It actually is `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`. When I copy/pasted the code here, I accidentally changed the parameters. Let me modify my post.

Comment: @heiglandreas I will give that a shot. Please await my feedback.

Comment: @heiglandreas I used move_upload_file and successfully got the file written to the desktop. However, when I use readImage(), I still get the same error even when I hardcode the path to the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on apple.stackexchange.com

I **answered** my own question over [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277251/homebrew-imagemagick-php54-imagick-not-working/277352#277352).