# Change tmp for ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagick

My tmp folder is getting spammed by imagemagick files. I want to change the path where the temporary files are saved so i can delete them with a script. For that I have tried changing the path in the `policy.xml` but it is still using the `/tmp/` folder. The method `setRegistry()`, [suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868089/set-php-imagemagick-tmp-directory), does not seem to exist in the class `Imagick` and I don't know where find the [enviornment variables](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php) like `MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH`. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 4):

It can also be used directly in your `convert` commands with `-define registry:temporary-path`. Example:

```
convert -define registry:temporary-path='/home/www/tmp_imagemagick' file1.jpg file2.png
```

Comment: Is this just for the explicit file file1.jpg file2.png or is the variable then set to the path `/home/www/tmp_imagemagick`?

Comment: It is just a basic example with two imaginary files, and you can set the temporary-path wherever you want on your server.

Answer (score 0):

In unix, you can edit your .profile or .bash_profile file located in our home directory to include: 
export MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH="yourdesiredlocation"

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that (obviously ;) ). But it didn't work. I have changed it but the `/tmp` path is still used :/

Comment: Did you reboot after editing your .profile?  In my .profile, I use "export TMPDIR=/tmp". You can try that, setting it to your desired directory.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting left with those temporary ImageMagick files in /tmp. They should be deleted automatically. The would only occur when, for example, a crash left them there before they could be deleted. Have you checked your permissions on /tmp to be sure they can be deleted.

Comment: I found tons of reports on that behavior. I think it is because ImageMagick cannot handle some of the PDFs. Because of that it doesn't delete those files. I'm not sure about this but this is my guess on it. @fmw42 no I didn't reboot, gonna try that. I am using a cronjob right now as a workaround